# How to extend symfony entity in bundle

Tags: php, symfony, inheritance, orm, doctrine

Is there a way I can extend a symfony entity in another bundle using `@DiscriminatorMap` without having to specify it beforehand?

**BundleA**

- Has a class `AbstractQueueItem` which is a `MappedSuperclass`for
- `Event` which is extended by
- `CreateEvent` and `DeleteEvent` as [`Single Table Inheritene`](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#single-table-inheritance) or [`Class Table Inheritence`](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#class-table-inheritance)

**BundleB**

- How can I add a new Event (i.e. `UpdateEvent`) to the `Event`-hierarchy without modifing `BundleA`?

Answer (score 1):

You can try letting doctrine auto-generate the discriminator map.
From the last bullet point in [this section of the docs](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#single-table-inheritance):

> If no discriminator map is provided, then the map is generated
>   automatically. The automatically generated discriminator map contains
>   the lowercase short name of each class as key.
>   So you would:

1. Omit the `@DiscriminatorMap` declaration in BundleA.
2. Extend the entity as normal in BundleB (making sure the short name of each class is unique).
3. Update the database schema.

**EDIT**
As pointed out by ju_ in the comments, this solution will apparently not work with Doctrine ORM 3.0, but should still be valid for versions [2.5](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.5/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#single-table-inheritance) - [2.7](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#single-table-inheritance)

Comment: I just noticed, that you referenced an outdated version of the docs. In the latest docs it states that an exception will be thrown if no descriminator map is given. See https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#single-table-inheritance

Comment: Thanks @ju_ I didn't realize I was viewing an older version, I added to my answer

Comment: As I am using a newer version, do you have any hints how to solve the problem without the auto discovery?